# VB.Net: using multiple parameter input from multiple textbox to run .exe

Tags: vb.net

I have created a form which will run a .exe file say test.exe and take the input from a textbox.
The code I have written

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("E:\My_programme\test\test.exe", TextBox1.Text)
```

This works fine

Now I need another program to run which takes 2 inputs from 2 different textbox.
The code I have written

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("E:\My_programme\test\test.exe", TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
```

Its showing Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Start' accepts this number of arguments

The normal procedure to run the test.exe from command prompt is

```
E:\My_programme\test\test.exe", A, B
```

where A and B are two parameters to be given in the two textbox.

I am very new to Visual Basic, so anybody please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass multiple command line arguments in a Program called in VB.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383063/how-to-pass-multiple-command-line-arguments-in-a-program-called-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` method only accepts a `String` defining the path to the `.exe` and a second `String` defining the parameters. Try:

```
Dim parameters as String
parameters = String.Format("{0} {1}", TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("E:\My_programme\test\test.exe", parameters)
```

This will create one string out of the two `TextBoxes` and forward it to the `test.exe` as input.

Answer (score 1):

Put your arguments in `StartInfo.Arguments`

```
  Dim p As New System.Diagnostics.Process
  p.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\My_programme\test\test.exe"
  p.StartInfo.Arguments = TextBox1.Text &" "& TextBox2.Text
  p.Start()
```